# How to adjust navigation tool bar width for iphone and ipad?

Tags: php, html, css, iphone, ipad

I am developing a webpage for both iphone and ipad . I created a navigation tool bar that looks ok on ipad but on iphone only two of the hyperlinks shows up ! Could any one tell me how I can shrink the navigation tool bar so all the hyperlinks show up on iphone 6 screen ?(I want all the navigation bar hyperlinks show up on both iphone and ipad). Thanks in advance?

```css
  ul#navigation {
    height: 70px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Cham-WebFont', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    /* new */
    bottom: 0;
    /* new */
    width: 100%;
    /* new */
  }
  ul#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .75em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul#navigation li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #MenuContainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  #MenuContainer a {
    margin: 0px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./TEST.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="MenuContainer">
  <ul id="navigation">

    <li class="x">
      <a title="1" href="./test.php?a">
        <img id="Button1" src="./1.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">First</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="2" href="./test.php" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?b&id='+currentID;return false;">
        <img id="Button2" src="./2.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Second</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="3" href="./test.php?c">
        <img id="Button3" src="./2.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Third</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="4" href="./test.php?d">
        <img id="Button4" src="./3.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Fourth</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="5" href="./test.php?e">
        <img id="Button5" src="./4.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Fifth</div>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply use percentage width for each `li` and have them as floated blocks or inline-blocks. I wouldn't recommend this as 5 links in one row in a small screen device not might be the most user friendly. Your decision.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `height:70px;` to `max-height: 100%; min-height:70px;`

**See Snippet:**

```css
ul#navigation {
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height:70px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Cham-WebFont', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    /* new */
    bottom: 0;
    /* new */
    width: 100%;
    /* new */
  }
  ul#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .75em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul#navigation li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #MenuContainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  #MenuContainer a {
    margin: 0px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div id="MenuContainer">
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li class="x">
      <a title="1" href="./test.php?a">
        <img id="Button1" src="./1.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">First</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="2" href="./test.php" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?b&id='+currentID;return false;">
        <img id="Button2" src="./2.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Second</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="3" href="./test.php?c">
        <img id="Button3" src="./2.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Third</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="4" href="./test.php?d">
        <img id="Button4" src="./3.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Fourth</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="x">
      <a title="5" href="./test.php?e">
        <img id="Button5" src="./4.png" alt="" width="42" height="42" border="0">
        <div class="caption">Fifth</div>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . I tested it on ipad it shows 4 of hyperlinks out of 5 and on iphone it shows 3 hyperlink in first row and only part of the other two hyperlink in  second row ?Is there away to show all 5 hyprlinks on one row in both devices or show 3 in one row and 2 in second row?

Comment: @user1788736 you could always look at dropdowns @ https://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/ or shrink the li proportionately to the device width evenly but it could cause the problem of accidently pressing the wrong link if too small.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting dropdown method I will test that option later.I changed the font of text on css and i got some more space . How i can decrease the gap between different hyperlinks ?

Comment: @user1788736 just reduce the margin on #MenuContainer a